# Show that there are infinitely many $x\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)$ is not prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, congruences

Let $f(x)$ denote a polynomial of degree at least $1$ with integer coefficients and positive leading coefficient.

(i)  Show that if $f(x_0)  =m >0$,  then $$f(x)\equiv0 \mod m$$  whenever $$x\equiv x_0 \mod m.$$
(ii) Show that there are infinitely many $x\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)$ is not prime.

I have finished the first question but can someone help me with the second part? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is an integer polynomial, then $f(x+D)-f(x)$ is always divisible by $D$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.